# Golang x509 certificate has OID values AS PRINTABLESTRING instead of UTF8STRING

Tags: go, x509certificate, x509, asn.1

go version  go1.18.4, darwin/arm64

I am creating x509 certificate.

when I parse the generated pem certificate using

```
asn1parse -in
```

I can see the common name as PRINTABLESTRING instead of UTF8STRING.

```
31:d=4 hl=2 l= 13 cons: SEQUENCE
33:d=5 hl=2 l= 3 prim: OBJECT :commonName
38:d=5 hl=2 l= 6 prim: PRINTABLESTRING :golang
```

as I understand, in golang the string is default utf8 but still certificate shows it as PRINTABLESTRING

The code is available at [GO play url](https://go.dev/play/p/hRSlYhoh-Rx)

Also,
when I put some characters like é um then I can see it as UTF8STRING.

Is there a way to put OID values as UTF8STRING instead of PRINTABLESTRING?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Go `asn1` package will only use `UTF8STRING` [if the string requires it](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/cf93b25366aa418dea3eea49a7b85447631c2a1d/src/encoding/asn1/marshal.go#L640-L651). There is nothing inherently wrong with this, and allowing the library to make this choice seems fine.

That said, if you *really* want to have `UTF8STRING` used, you may be able to use `asn1.RawValue` to achieve this:

```
name, err := asn1.MarshalWithParams("golang", "utf8")
if err != nil {
    // handle error
}

pkixAttrTypeValue := []pkix.AttributeTypeAndValue{
    {
        Type:  COMMON_NAME,
        Value: asn1.RawValue{FullBytes: name},
    },
}
```